# pushViewController only works with animated:YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have found a strange behaviour when trying to push a viewcontroller onto the stack. The following works fine:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

but if I change it to `animated:NO` it no longer works, doesn't seem to push at all. I was performing this in a `viewWillAppear` but I have also tried it in `viewDidAppear` but with no luck.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably not the call itself, but the placement of the call.   Try putting the same action on a UIButton and it should 100% work.   I've noticed that putting view controller manipulation routines like presentModal... and pushViewController... don't sometimes work in the viewWill* viewDid* methods.   Or try making the calls from those functions with a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay after a short delay and see if that works.

Edit: there are a couple of ways of doing what you want to do.   You can directly modify the navigation stack of a navigation controller, so when you are in view N+1, you can replace view N on the stack (by building a new navigation stack array and setting it in to the navigation controller), then pop, and you'll get the effect of "popping back to a different view controller".   You can also issue multiple pops and pushes from the view controller you want to leave, but you have to be careful:

```
// pop back 2 controllers on the stack to the setup screen
//

// locally store the navigation controller since
// self.navigationController will be nil once we are popped
//
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

// retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
//
[[self retain] autorelease];

// Pop back 2 controllers to the setup screen
//
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It does indeed work when done as an action on a UIButton. The problem is I am doing this when returning from another viewcontroller and I  want to be able to change the previous visible viewcontroller before the viewcontroller I am returning from is removed from view.